# MySQL GroupBy and Shows it horizontally

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, pivot

Supposed that I have table below:

```
1) tblScore

============================ 
Date      VendorID     Score 
============================ 
12/09/01  12001        A     
12/09/01  12001        A     
12/09/01  12002        B     
12/09/02  12003        C     
12/09/02  12003        A     
12/09/03  12001        C     
============================
```

I have this query:

```
SELECT ts.VendorID, ts.Score, COUNT(*)
FROM trxscore ts
GROUP BY ts.VendorID, ts.Score
ORDER BY ts.VendorID, ts.Score
```

But how to show the table like:

```
===========================
VendorID    A    B    C
===========================
12001       2    0    1
12002       0    1    0 
12003       1    0    1
===========================
```

And, is it possible to get an average from a text? i.e., `VendorID 12001` should get the average of A. Thanks...

Comment: I don't understand the way you calculate the avg. Can you explain more ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT  VendorID,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Score = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalA,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Score = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalB,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Score = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalC
FROM    tableName
GROUP BY VendorID
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1de17/2)

Comment: Thanks, it works great! :) .. Btw, is it possible to get the average from that score?

Comment: you are welcome, btw, what do you by average? for example, `12001` should get `1`?

Comment: No, it means: When `12001` get score: A, A, A, B, C, C, then the average should be `A`. It's not average, but the maximum value, sorry..

Comment: @mrjimoy_05 [is this what you want? >click here<](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1de17/21)

Comment: Exactly. Thanks for your kindness answering my extending question. :)