# Storing result of a SQL query and applying partitions on it to find top 3 entries for each user

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I am running a SQL (mysql) query which results in a table like below and is not stored anywhere
Now for each user based on count, I need to fetch the top 3 values. I tried to work with partitions but it fails as result is not in any table.

```
-----------------------------------------
pkid | username | genre     | count|
-----------------------------------------
1     user1      Horror         7
2     user1      Comedy         3
3     user1      Romantic       2
4     user1      Documentary    1
5     user2      Documentary    9
6     user2      Chik-Flick     5
7     user3      Romantic       12
```

I am trying to get output something like this

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
pkid | username | genre1    | count1|   genre2| count2 | genre3 | count3
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     user1      Horror         7     Comedy      3      Romantic    2
2     user2      Documentary    9     Chik-Flik   5      Null       Null
3     user3      Romantic       12    Null        Null   Null       Null
```

I tried:

```
WITH temp1 (username,genre,Count1) AS 
    (<My query which gave result shared>) 
SELECT username,genre, Count1 
FROM ( 
    SELECT username,genre, Count1 
    Rank() over (Partition BY username ORDER BY Count1 DESC ) AS Rank 
    FROM temp1 
) WHERE temp1 Rank <= 3
```

Any Pointers?

Comment: Show what you tried to do with partitions. Putting them horizontally is a pivot.

Comment: WITH temp1 (username,genre,Count1) AS (<My query which gave result shared>)
SELECT username,genre, Count1
FROM (
SELECT username,genre, Count1 Rank()
over (Partition BY username
ORDER BY Count1 DESC ) AS Rank
FROM temp1
) WHERE temp1 Rank <= 3

Comment: You have to assign an alias to the subquery.

Comment: I think you're missing a comma before the `RANK()` call.

Comment: Added the comma, still facing the same issue.
Is it because the result is not stored anywhere as a table?

Comment: Here is another question answered. This is not same as you expect in output, but this shows that you can use your genre name as column name and display count as value.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12666796/mysql-groupby-and-shows-it-horizontally